# Trying to find a way to only display a section of script once in Shopify.

Tags: javascript, shopify, liquid

I have previously used {% if first_time_accessed %} to handle this condition for the order status / checkout receipt pages, but I'm now trying to only display something the first time that it is accessed.

For clarity, this is the structure of the content:

```
// Check User is logged in
{% if customer %}
  // Check that the pixel has not yet been displayed
  {% if INSERT CONDITION FOR FIRST ITERATION HERE %}

    // Run JS Script
```

So ideally the if customer will cause the JS script to run only on the first page the customer visits after logging into their account.

Any thoughts or suggestions on how to achieve this would be great. I'm beginning to think the easy approach would be to set a cookie with the status for this condition but that seems like a long way around it.

Thanks!

Comment: What are you trying to achieve ultimately? There can be another solution..

Comment: The goal is to make sure the js script only runs on the first page the user visits after logging in.

Answer (score 0):

The solution would need to be javascript since there is nothing to do this in Liquid, except on the Checkout page as you have mentioned.